# Has "Cannot read property of undefined" error message been changed?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, bitbucket-pipelines

Today I was running my jest unit tests on Bitbucket pipeline and got failed due to different error message (see payload on screenshot below). They pass successfully on my local PC, but failed on Bitbucket.

It display "Cannot read property '...' of undefined"  on my local PC, but "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '...')" on bitbucket

Any ideas why message of standard error is different?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was is different node version.

Once I have pinned node version in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file to 14.16.0

`image: node:14.16.0-slim`

Everything is fine